# How to open a file without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and a binary file within extension's folder. How should I open the file and read it without interaction through input? The only way I see is to pull it from some CDN storage. But the file eats up to 50 mb, so it's not an option for me.

Comment: Do you package this file with the extension or is it generated after install? Maybe share more details of what problem is being solved with this file, there may be a better way? Anyway, you can [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) extension files in the same directory, use relative path.

Comment: Fetch actually works for me, thank you!
It's a static file that goes with extension. It contains binary data to be read as BigUint64Array